# Display grep output in table columns

Tags: shell-script, scripting, text-formatting

I need to display grep output in table columns.

I have a script that grab info from whois to display the creation, expiry date and ns server of specific domain names.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat domain-file.txt  | while read line ; do
lLine="$(echo $line | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
echo "$lLine\t" >> table.csv;
sleep 3
echo "\n$lLine"
host=whois.nic.re
created=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'created:')
echo "$created\t" >> table.csv
sleep 2
expire=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'Expiry Date:')
echo "$expire\t" >> table.csv
sleep 2
nserver=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'nserver:')
echo "$nserver\t" >> table.csv
echo "------------------------------------------" >> table.csv
done
exit
```

Everything is working well except that im trying to display the output in a table like this :

```
Domain          Created Date    Expiry date     NS
abcd.com        19/01/2018      19/01/2019      ns.abcd.com ns2.abcd.com
1234.com        19/01/2018      19/01/2019      ns.1234.com ns2.1234.com
```

Instead im getting an output like that :

```
abcd.com        
Created date: 19/01/2018        
Expiry date: 19/01/2019         
nserver: ns.abcd.com 
nserver: ns2.abcd.com
------------------------------------------
1234.com        
Created date: 19/01/2018        
Expiry date: 19/01/2019         
nserver: ns.1234.com 
nserver: ns2.1234.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use comma as a delimiter for CSV files for a better view in opencalc or excel. Try the following code which I have not tested.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "Domain,Created Date,Expiry_date,NS" > table.csv
cat domain-file.txt  | while read line ; 
do
    lLine="$(echo $line | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
    host=whois.nic.re
    created=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'created:' | awk -F ':' '{print $NF}')
    expire=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'Expiry Date:' | awk -F ':' '{print $NF}')
    nserver=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'nserver:' | awk -F ':' '{print $NF}')
    echo -e "$lLine,$created,$expire,$nserver" >> table.csv
done
exit
```

To view result on terminal:

```
 column -t -s',' table.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying that , you are able to save information in csv with delimiter `TAB` i.e. `\t` and goal of asking this problem is to pretty print the data in columns

Just try this, and it will work

```
column  -t -s$'\t' -n table.csv
```